# Use the argument command itself instead of its argument in newcommand

Tags: macros, expansion

I want to implement a macro, that uses the command passed in the first argument as the command itself, not as the content passed by evaluating it. Something like:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{bar}
% definition
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{
    \dosomethingwith{???}% I want \foo here, not 'bar'
}
\mycmd{\foo}
```

Comment: I don't follow: if you do `\mycmd{\foo}` then `#1` in `\mycomd` is '`\foo`'.

Comment: As Joseph says, `#1` will be `\foo` and not `bar`: TeX won't do macro expansion when absorbing arguments. So you should be clearer about your aims.

Comment: Thanks on that hint. I didn't know the macro expansion works in that way. I wanted to do something like: `\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{\expandafter\renewcommand{#1}{BAR}}` and I got it now with `\expandafter`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\expandafter\renewcommand{#1` expands `{` which is not expandable, you want  `\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter{#1` or just `\expandafter\renewcommand#1`

Comment: @David Carlisle Wow, you're right! My `\expandafter` did nothing there.

Comment: @delbertooo You don't need *any* `\expandafter`. Did you try `\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{\renewcommand{#1}{BAR}}` and `\mycmd{\foo}`? Which works and redefines `\foo` to mean `BAR`.

Answer (score 2):

With the following preliminary code

```
\newcommand{\foo}{bar}
% definition
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{%
    \dosomethingwith{#1}%
}
```

the call

```
\mycmd{\foo}
```

will make TeX replace `\mycmd` and its argument `\foo` with

```
\dosomethingwith{\foo}
```

and *no* expansion of `\foo` will be attempted yet. What TeX will do is expand `\dosomethingwith`, which might mean looking for an argument, but again `\foo` will still *not* be expanded.

So, the test case you outline in the comments is

```
\newcommand{\foo}{bar}
% definition
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{#1}{BAR}%
}
```

and attempting

```
\mycmd{\foo}
```

will do *exactly* what's espected, that is, changing the meaning of `\foo`.

#### Example document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} % we want to use `\meaning` for showing the meaning of commands

\newcommand{\foo}{bar}

\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{#1}{BAR}%
}
\mycmd{\foo}
\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\expandafter\renewcommand{#1
```

expands `{` which is not expandable, you want

```
\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter{#1
```

or just

```
\expandafter\renewcommand#1
```

Comment: Of course, `\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter{#1}{BAR}}` with `\mycmd{\foo}` will result in a disaster if `\foo` expands to `bar` as in the example.

Comment: @egreg yes answering the implied question in the comments rather than the question as written, maybe the OP could clarify the original question...